# Fastlane multiple Targets Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, configuration, fastlane, white-framework

I'm working in a white label project where I need to use FASTLANE. I have already understood that I could create one env file for each project, for example:

env .App1
env .App2
env .App3
env .App4

but how about APPFILE? because I set the bundle identifier inside this file , however I'm working with multiple bundle identifiers inside my project. How Could I reference all of them inside the AppFile?

I need to reference all my bundle identifiers inside the APPFILE

Comment: Try to use xcconfigs + tust. In my case with while labels it was the ultimate solution

Answer (score 0):

After a time I noted that Appfile will know the correct env file, because it has global variables, so it is not necessary to specify.